# CRON Permission Denied

Tags: debian, cron

I have a Debian 7. 3 Server with WebMin installed. I configured a cron job to run every minute as root user, so I run the command crontab -l when I'm logged in as root it shows:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/myfolder/cron.php
```

The permissions of that file are the following:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1617 Jan 18 15:17 /home/myfolder/cron.php
```

When I go to the cron.log file in /var/log folder I see this error repeated every minute:

```
Apr 16 12:25:01 ns3313699 CRON[25370]: Permission denied
```

the result of the command ls -ld /usr/bin/php /home/myfolder is:

```
drwxrwxr-x 20 myfolder www-data 4096 Apr 16 11:43 /home/myfolder
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan 18 11:05 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
```

Comment: Change your cron command to `/home/myfolder/cron.php 2> /home/myfolder/errror`. That will save any errors printed to `/home/myfolder/errror`. Please [edit] your question and add those errors.

Comment: Done, but I cannot see ant errror file in /home/myfolder

Comment: OK, that means that the `cron` is not running and the error occurs before the script is run. Can you run `/usr/bin/php -q /home/myfolder/cron.php` from the command line as root?

Comment: yes sure, and it works

Comment: @LucaCoppola are you sure to perform the crontab as root ? no sudo involved ?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: the log says this : Apr 16 12:25:01 ns3313699 CRON[25370]: Permission denied

@Kiwy How do I check this?

Comment: @LucaCoppola - what's the file `cron.php` attempting to do? To confirm I'd try a simple cron first using Bash, and make sure that this "hello cron" script works and then work your way up.

Comment: is a simple file that should send email .. made to test if cron works

Comment: @LucaCoppola Can you post it then? I'd like to try it on my end to replicate your issue further.

Comment: <?php

mail('myemail@email.com','hello luca','hello');

?>

Comment: @LucaCoppola Please add the output of `ls -ld /usr/bin/php /home/myfolder` to your question.

Comment: ok now you can see it at the bottom of the question

Comment: I suggest trying `strace -f -p \`pidof cron\`` and see if you can't find out where that permission denied is coming from. (That will make a *lot* of output, you'll want to become familiar with strace before trying it...)

Comment: This message is from cron, not from PHP. What are the permissions on the crontab file?

Comment: Take a look at these 2 Q&A's from SF and AU. [Cron: Permission denied on everything](http://serverfault.com/questions/274434/cron-permission-denied-on-everything) & [All commands in my crontab fail with “Permission denied”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/296107/all-commands-in-my-crontab-fail-with-permission-denied)

Comment: @derobert Thus it makes a lot of sense to start with `strace -f -e trace=open -p $pidofcron` or `strace -f -e trace=file -p $pidofcron`

Comment: @Gilles The permissions should matter only if `cron` is not running as root. Otherwise there must be some LSM active (AppArmor, SELinux).